# Is there a way to improve Windows 10 Multi Screen support?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I've installed a second monitor on a Windows 10 Pro computer. Some features are missing:

1. Alt-TAB only pops on screen 1. It should either pop on the screen with the current focus, or on both (like Win-TAB)
2. When I click on an icon in the task bar, it brings the app up, but if it's on the other - it's easy to miss it. Could there be some sort of indication that the window is on the other screen (maybe an arrow pointing to the other screen - the order of the screens can be configured in the Display settings)
3. This is obviously not the same as the first two, and requires a camera. But if Windows could detect which screen I'm *looking at*, and change the keyboard focus to the topmost window on that screen, that would be magnificent.

Comment: Well, this is not a site to suggest feature requests. What you want is not natively possible in Windows and will most likely require (paid) software to accomplish.

Comment: I am not suggesting a feature, I'm looking for this software you mentioned (paid or otherwise) - as I couldn't find anything.